# Base Drive Circuit

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I've been experimenting on Half Bridge converter and there is something that I can not understand. What is the purpose of the diodes and capacitor (red one in the picture) in base drive circuit. I check and realize most  of base drive has it. why the emitters if Q3 and Q4 are not connected to the ground directly?[image]

Comment: you have selected a very good circuit to learn on .The details of Q3 and Q4 and how it starts are very subtle .I do not know why R51 and R52 are not the same value .Is it a misprint?

Comment: This is an old AT PC PSU. TL494 is used here as open collector output. So, to make sure that TL494 open collector output will be able to cut-off Q3 and Q4 properly, the designer add D18, D19 diodes in the Q3 and Q4 emitters to rise turn-on voltage.

Answer (score 1):

This technique biases both emitters of Q3,Q4 at 2 diode drops or 1.4V while the base voltage toggles from 0 to 2V at some fast rate like 40~50kHz.

These Push-Pull drivers are never on at the same time but the secondary high voltage drivers Q1,Q2 could be if the the primary Q3,Q4 are slow to turn off.

It's all about Miller Capacitance and minimizing the turn off time when turning each of Q3,Q4 into the OFF state by reverse biasing the base emitter by 2 diode drops.

The base collector capacitance is much higher if the emitter is grounded and the base voltage goes to 0V while the collector voltage was saturated near 0V and you ought to know that diode capacitance or the base collector junction is maximum at OV and reduces sharply as it becomes reverse biased thus speeding up the rise in collector voltage. In fact, the collector voltage may be quite large, from V=LdI/dt depending on core inductance and slew rate but very short in duration. THe net effect is that the secondary turn off times are also reduced so they do not overlap with both Q1,Q2 being on at the same time across the high voltage DC bridge rectifier used to power the high power transformer.

This technique is to provide rapid switch with minimum deadtime needed to commutate (toggle) the 2nd stage bridge transistors, Q1,Q2 and avoid shoot-thru fatal effects.

Comment: But in this circuit, Q3 and Q2 are ON at the same time (especially at low loads). But the "driver trafo"is wound on a core in such a way so that the flux cancels out.

Comment: THat's weird, then how does it work? like a Flyback transformer rather than a Push-Pull? Yet base drive non-inverted with center tap to 12V and primary tap windings inverted wrt schematic ( no dots shown) would add in flux  , not cancel, leading to  saturation.   In any case the 2 emitter diodes +cap speed up turnoff times for Vbe=+0.7 to -1.4V

Comment: I will try to find some o-scope captures.

Comment: Is D18 connected to the emitter of Q3 and Q4? I can't tell if there is a connection dot or not.

Comment: It is rather sloppy , but yet it should be connected to emitters and anode

Comment: What are D20 and D22 for? They look a bit like flyback diodes but the path doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: I agree . D20,D22 must be  TVS diodes (Zener) I chose 24V here with 20mH http://tinyurl.com/y6mtkslb

Comment: I don't yet know why the pull down R's are there or why they are different  http://tinyurl.com/yykkajzh